# PHP find out the value of the next index in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, smarty

I have the following problem. I have a array with the following structure.

my $array is:

```
array[0].amount = 10;
array[1].amount = 20;
array[2].amount = 30;
```

I am working on a .tpl file.
I want to compare e.g. the (A) value 10 with (B) 10 and (C) 20 There is a discount if (A) is greater than or equal to (B) 10 and less than (C) 20 However, I do not get the value (C). I have many methods tried, but I get a blank white page (Syntax Error).

```
<script> 
  function myFunction(){
    {foreach $array as $item key=id}
      var amount = {$item.amount};
      var amountNext = {$array[id+1].amount}; //on the next loop amountNext is still 10
      if(10 >= amount && 10 < amountNext){
        //do something
      }
    {/foreach} 
  }
</script>
```

-- edit --
Now I found another method to get the next index, but doesn't work yet:

```
{section name=id loop=$array}
  var a = {$array[id.index].amount}; // a is 10
  var b = {$array[id.index_next].amount}; // not working
{/section}
```

[Source](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.section.tpl)

Comment: What templating engine are you using? It looks like probably Smarty.

Comment: yes it´s smarty for JTL-Online Store Shop